# Difference between external and internal library in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to understand the difference between external and internal library in Jenkins pipeline.
I read the [Extending with Shared Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). It says about the **libraryResource step** such:

> A resources directory allows the libraryResource step to be used from an **external library** to load associated non-Groovy files. Currently this feature is not supported for **internal libraries**.

What do the external and internal mean? I guess that:

- Internal library is gotten from a repository which is the same with a Jenkinsfile
- External library is gotten from a repository which is **not** the same with a Jenkinsfile

Is my understanding right?
Thanks.

Comment: My first impression was this was a "typo" regarding trusted/untrusted libraries, but that does not seem to be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line in documentation [has been added a 2016](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/commit/8421597ad6f5592bf16716367b3fef88431d20be#diff-747b7ea0dc5eac623a4dbdbe6d36b009039ee4f8567871726c12d8fb124c5edeR57), and in the same commit there is [a reference to "internal" libraries being "legacy"](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/commit/8421597ad6f5592bf16716367b3fef88431d20be#diff-747b7ea0dc5eac623a4dbdbe6d36b009039ee4f8567871726c12d8fb124c5edeR125).

I have worked some time with Jenkins Pipeline now, and until now never heard of "internal" Pipelines -- I think for Pipeline Libraries as they are defined in 2022 are always "external".

---

Edit: Only some month before the line was added to documentation, a  [[JENKINS-31155] Shared libraries](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/pull/10) PR was merged to the plugin implementing Shared Libraries.

If you check [the readme at that time](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/1b70381dbda34e6fd9acb15b4c206e9aec75c965/README.md#defining-the-internal-library), it tells:

> ### Defining the internal library
>
> An older mode of sharing code is to deploy sources to Jenkins itself. [...]

Thus:

- External Library: Pushed to a SCM outside Jenkins.
- Internal library: Pushed to a Git Repo within Jenkins. (Legacy, not supported anymore)

Comment: Grateful for your comment.
I found vestiges I want to know such:
    [Removed (1)](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/commit/ce79b63b8093ff043a416ca7bc47464682bccc4a#diff-747b7ea0dc5eac623a4dbdbe6d36b009039ee4f8567871726c12d8fb124c5edeL124-L127)
    [Removed (2)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/commit/c9059ddb9fb4e6db2c57524d1ce155bbdc0a82ad)
Your answer is extremetly helpful.